# How to apply the external css style specific to an html file?

Tags: html, css

I have 5 html files and 1 css file.When I link this external css to all the html files, all the styles are getting applied to all the file. But I wanted only few styles to be used.How can I make it?

Eg:

```
    <head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///C:/Users/myuser/Pictures/HTML/Styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">            </script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>


body
{
  background-image: url("file://C:/Users/myuser/Pictures/HTML/bicycles.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

}
```

Here, the body style is getting applied to all the html files and an unwanted background is being displayed.Please let me know how can I resolve this.

Comment: CSS selectors are your friend  - create and use specific ids / classes in the required files to target specific divs / elements

Comment: try having class/id for different body tags/wrapper divs

Comment: Thank you guys gav and Dipali ..